# v8::Object::SetAccessor - How does it work?

Tags: v8, javascript-engine

There's no documentation on "v8::Object::SetAccessor" - is it correct to assume I can set a different setter and getter function for each specified property name?  How does this affect the object if it was created from an object template? (yes, I know I can set it on a template, I'm just curious about possible conflicts)